# Trying to parse an error returned from an Observable

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

In Angular 7, I'm calling into our MS WebApi and receiving an error response which I cannot seem to parse out properly.
The raw response looks like this:

```js
"{"Message":"Add System Instance Failed", "MessageDetail":"2; Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.SystemInstanceTbl' with unique index 'IX_SystemInstanceTbl'. The duplicate key value is (The_Duplicate_Value).
The statement has been terminated.", "ErrorCode":"50105952", "Exception":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Objects.FaultDetail]: Add  System Instance Failed."}"
```

The error response comes back as object:

```
 error.error
```

But `JSON.parse(error.error)` throws a JSON error `Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 242`.

What's the cleanest way to pull out the `Message` and `MessageDetail` properties ?

My error handler is as follows :

```js
protected handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {    
    let err = (error && error.message !== undefined) ? error.message : '';  

    
    console.log(err);    
    return throwError(err);
  }
```

Comment: How/where in your Angular code are you specifically attempting to extract those values, please update your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is that the JSON string contains some new line characters.

You can replace those with spaces, here is an example:

```js
let jsonStr = `{"Message":"Add System Instance Failed", "MessageDetail":"2; Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.SystemInstanceTbl' with unique index 'IX_SystemInstanceTbl'. The duplicate key value is (The_Duplicate_Value).
The statement has been terminated.", "ErrorCode":"50105952", "Exception":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException\`1[Objects.FaultDetail]: Add  System Instance Failed."}`;

jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(/\n/g, " ");

const data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: IMHO, the original message is not properly formatted - new line character should be escaped. It should be fixed at backend api, not hacked here

Comment: I will give it a try.